# JQuery returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to turn a table into a JSON object with the following function:

```js
turnTableIntoJSON(table)
  {
    let jquery = require("jquery");
    const $: JQueryStatic = jquery
    let myRows = []
    let headersText = []
    let $headers = $("th")
    var $rows = $("tbody  tr").each(function(index)
    {
      let $cells = $(this).find("th")
      myRows[index] = {};

      $cells.each(function (cellIndex)
      {
        if(headersText[cellIndex] == undefined)
        {
          headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
        }
        myRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
      })
    })
    let myObj = {"myRows": myRows}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj))

  }
```

but the console is logging for me an empty object for some reason, I have tried passing the table as a parameter as well with the same result, not sure why this is. No error output or anything just an empty object.

For reference this is how the table is configured in the HTML:

```html
 <table id="rfqTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center" border="1">
    <tr align="left">
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>header 5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9 | Price</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th>13</th>
      <th>14</th>
      <th>15</th>
      <th>16 UoM</th>
      <th>17</th>
      <th>18</th>
      <th>19</th>
    </tr>
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of priceRecords ; let id = index">
    <tr *ngIf="i.hide==false" align="left">
      <th>{{id}}#{{i.bomPart.item}}</th>
      <th>{{i.bomPart.mfg}}</th>
      <th>{{i.bomPart.mpn}}</th>
      <th><span class="input" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'mfg', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'mfg', $event)" contenteditable="true" >{{i.mfg}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'mpn', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'mpn', $event)" contenteditable="true" >{{i.mpn}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'minOrderQty', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'minOrderQty', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.minOrderQty}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'multOrderQty', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'multOrderQty', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.multOrderQty}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'inventory', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'inventory', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.inventory}}</span></th>
      <th >  
        <table border="0"  width="150">
          <tr *ngFor="let j of i.breakPrice ; let ii = index "> 
            <td><span  class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, '', $event)" (blur)="updateList2(id,'breakPrice',ii,'quantity', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{j?.quantity}}</span></td>
            <td><span  class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, '', $event)" (blur)="updateList2(id,'breakPrice',ii,'price', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{j?.price}}</span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'registrationprice', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'registrationprice', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.registrationprice}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'nonRecurringExpenses', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'nonRecurringExpenses', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.nonRecurringExpenses}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="YesNo" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'obsolete', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'obsolete', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.obsolete}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="number" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'leadWeeks', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'leadWeeks', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.leadWeeks}}</span></th>
      <th><span class="input" type="YesNo" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'nonCancelableNonReturnable', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'nonCancelableNonReturnable', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.nonCancelableNonReturnable}}</span></th>
      <th>
        <table border="0">
          <tr *ngFor="let j of i.volumePrice"> 
            <td>{{j?.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{j?.price}} </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>{{i.bomPart.uom}}</th>
      <th><span class="input" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'uom', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'uom', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.uom}}</span></th>
      <th >{{i.bomPart.description}}</th>
      <th><span class="input" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'notes', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'notes', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{i.notes}}</span></th>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML of the table you're trying to read, and also the JSON result you're expecting. I just made a demo with an arbitrary table, and it can produce results, although I suspect probably not what you were hoping for: see https://jsfiddle.net/wkn1cxbd/ . It's unclear what you would intend the output to be in that situation.

Comment: sure give me one second I was actually just about to add it in an edit

Comment: Actually a better version, with some headers: https://jsfiddle.net/wkn1cxbd/1/ seems to produce a better result. Is that what you would want / expect? Based on that, I can't see anything obviously the matter with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your table doesn't contain a `<tbody>` so `$("tbody  tr")` will never select any rows. Also that doesn't look like the final rendered table, it looks like it's got Angular code in it. Would be better to show the finished HTML really, since that's what jQuery will be working with. But anyway the lack of a tbody is the crucial point.

Comment: yeah it does have some angular code in it the table is dependent on some data it's different for each page

Comment: well that's an aside really. The lack of a `<tbody>` is the important thing.

Comment: you're right I added a tbody outside the ng-container

Comment: Seeing that you have an <ng-container> tag I'm guessing you are using Angular. You might be able to find the issue if you check if the table is rendered before you call turnTableIntoJSON(). Another thing is you could add a console log inside the each function and check the values being assigned to myRows

Comment: I thought this too but the function is called with onClick after the table is rendered

Comment: actually, @ADyson is right, you don't have a tbody on the html at all..

Comment: yes I added it in just haven't edited the snippet my bad

Comment: Yes, add a `<tbody></tbody>` but also wrap your header in `<thead></thead>`. Thus (if all table cells must be `<th></th>`), then you have the means of selecting header cells independently from body cells. As it stands, `$("th");` selects *all* cells in the table whereas you are only interested in the actual header cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery always creates a jQuery object when trying to select an element. Even it's not on your DOM (n.fn.init)

I think `$("tbody  tr")` is an undefined target or malformed selector that can be replaced with: `$('#rfqTable tr')` and should work as i don't see any tbody element on your code.
(if it's created by angular provide feedback for further investigation).

If it gives you a non-empty object, check also your table configuration as there's more than a tr level on your `#rfqTable` and it can cause issues. You may want to specify an ID to the parent element and some definition (like data-something for example) to mark which elements you want to select (or avoid others that you dont).

Comment: you are brilliant I should've though of that from the beginning but you solved it I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

With the table's header row wrapped in `<thead>...</thead>` and the table's body wrapped in `<tbody>...</tbody>` (as they should be), you might like to consider :

```
turnTableIntoJSON(table) {
    let jquery = require('jquery');
    const $: JQueryStatic = jquery;
    let headers = $(table).find('thead th').get().map(th => $(th).text());
    let myRows = $(table).find('tbody tr').get().map(tr => {
        let obj = {};
        $(tr).find('th').each(function(index, cell) {
            obj[headers[index]] = $(cell).text();
        });
        return obj;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ myRows }))
}
```